# Latexdiff adds .tex to image.eps_tex filename and then fails

Tags: eps, latexdiff

I have a publication done in Latex that needs track changes. When using latexdiff, I use --flatten to compile everything into one file. However, some of the figures have text in them, so I exported the eps images from inkscape with the fonts in a separate tex file. To import these images, I use the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \def\svgwidth{5cm}
    \input{images/specific_image.eps_tex}
    \caption{...}\label{...}
\end{figure}
```

Latexdiff adds ".tex" to the end of the file name making it "images/specific_image.eps_tex.tex", which of course it cannot find because it does not exist.

I have not seen any examples that include this type of image import. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: I don't know how to fix this in LaTeX (if that's even possible), but I would look at how to do renames after latexdiff in your process instead.

Comment: @enkorvaks, I went with your suggestion. I had to change the import names to the .eps files for latexdiff to work and then went and changed the imports back to the original afterwards. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: For this to work out of the box, the --flatten functionality within latexdiff would have to be modified slightly. You can add this as a feature request as issue on latexdiff github page.